# Newtyping smart pointers to recursive datatypes

Tags: rust

Here's my understanding of a problem I've encountered several times. Suppose I want to represent simple arithmetic expressions (integers, sums, products). If I want to allocate the nodes on the heap and I don't require shared ownership, then the most straightforward implementation appears to be:

```
enum Expr {
    Num(isize),
    Sum(Box<Expr>, Box<Expr>),
    Prod(Box<Expr>, Box<Expr>),
}

use Expr::*
```

With this definition, we can represent the expressions `1 + 2` and `3` as

```
let e1 = Sum(Box::new(Num(1)), Box::new(Num(2)));
let e2 = Num(3);
```

At the moment, the values bound to `e1` and `e2` are allocated on the stack, whereas the children of the sum `(Expr::Num(1)` and `Expr::Num(2))` are allocated on the heap. Consequently, the following

```
let e3 = Prod(Box::new(e1), Box::new(e2));
```

must first *copy* the values bound to `e1` and `e2` from their locations on the stack into the heap. We can avoid this copying by always working with Boxed `Expr`s. For instance:

```
let e1 = Box::new(Sum(Box::new(Num(1)), Box::new(Num(2))));
let e2 = Box::new(Num(3));
```

Then

```
let e3 = Box::new(Prod(e1, e2));
```

only requires copying two `Box`es from the stack to the heap. With this in mind, I'm inclined to define a new type that represents a Boxed expression and work directly with that:

```
struct Expr(Box<_Expr>);

enum _Expr {
    Num(isize),
    Sum(Expr, Expr),
    Prod(Expr, Expr),
}
```

This resembles the use of "opaque pointers" in C, since the Box is now "hidden" inside the (newtype) struct Expr.

What are your thoughts on this pattern? Is this a common way to work with recursive datatypes, or am I over/under-thinking some of the issues here?

Comment: You could potentially use a `type Expr = Box<_Expr>` alias instead, which will allow you to `impl _Expr` and have those methods work without any additional effort for `Expr` too.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, you might consider the arena pattern instead, where you allocate your nodes on a vector.

Comment: Thank you, folks! I like the type aliasing idea, @EvilTak; I'll give that a shot and see how it works. I also hadn't looked much into the arena pattern, but I think that would be a great fit for what I'm doing. Again, thanks for the thoughts and help.

Comment: *"Consequently, the following must first copy the values ... on the stack into the heap"* - it seems a dubious claim to me that `let e= Num(3); let be = Box::new(e);` would be functionally any different than `let be = Box::new(Num(3));`.

Comment: That's an interesting thought. I think I figured that `Box::new(Num(3))` would allocate enough space for `Num(3)` and then directly set the appropriate values on the heap, whereas the first would reserve space in the stack frame for `Num(3)`, then allocate, then copy from the stack to the new allocation. Either way, I think I'm probably worrying too much about this at the moment. Thanks for that thought. I'll see if I can determine how `Box::new` works by looking at some output with `objdump`.